# Extract HTML table content based on "thead"

Tags: css-selectors, html-table, text-processing, html-tableextract, html-xml-utils

Here is a basic HTML table :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td class="foo">bar</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>rows</td>
    …
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Suppose there are several such tables in the source file.  Is there an option of `hxextract`, or a CSS3 selector I could use with `hxselect`, or some other tool, which would allow to extract **one particular table**, either based on the content of `thead` or on its class if it exists ?  Or am I stuck with not so simple `awk` (or [maybe perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037220/extract-table-contents-using-perl), as found before submitting) scripting ?

**Update :**
For content-based extraction, perl's `HTML::TableExtract` does the trick :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use HTML::TableExtract;

# Extract tables based on header content, slice_columns helpful if colspan issues
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => ['Multi'], slice_columns => 0);
$te->parse_file('mywebpage.html');

# Loop on all matching tables
foreach $ts ($te->tables()) 
{
  # Print table identification
  print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";

  # Print table content
  foreach $row ($ts->rows) 
  {
    print join(':', @$row), "\n";
  }
}
```

However in some cases a simple `lynx -dump mywebpage.html` coupled wih `awk` or whatever can be just as efficient.

Comment: did you tried to parent selector?

$('foo').parent().parent()
//this will give you the table that has the foo class in the td

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work with `hxselect` or `hxextract`.  But anyway the syntax you suggest wouldn't work, so are you thinking about another (command line) tool ?

Comment: He's thinking about jQuery, a JavaScript library. You'll have to forgive folks around here for mistakenly assuming any question involving HTML must somehow involve a Web browser and therefore JavaScript, and that jQuery must be in use - it seems to happen all the time for some reason...

Comment: Well, I guess technically I *could* [use JS from CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941411/executing-javascript-without-a-browser)…

Comment: Oh yeah... node.js. Why not? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require a parent selector or a relational selector, [which does not as yet exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) (and by the time it does exist, `hxselect` may not implement it because it does not even fully implement the current standard as of this writing). `hxextract` appears to only retrieve an element by its type and/or class name, so the best it'd do is `td.foo`, which would return the `td` only, not its `thead` or `table`.

If you are processing this HTML from the command line, you will need a script.